# c++ static-init-fiasco example

Tags: c++, static-initialization

Learning C++ with help of "Thinking in C++" by Bruce Eckel,stuck in exercise 32, chapter 10.
The question is how to change link order, that Mirror::test() called for object m5 return false.
Here is my code.

#### mirror.h:

```
#ifndef MIRROR_H_
#define MIRROR_H_

class Mirror {
 public:
  Mirror() {logic_ = true; self_ = 0;};
  Mirror(Mirror *ptr) {self_ = ptr; logic_ = false;};
  bool test() {
    if (self_ != 0) {
      return self_->test();
    } else {
      return logic_;
    }
  };

 private:
  bool logic_;
  Mirror *self_;
};


#endif // MIRROR_H_
```

task

#### one.cpp

```
#include "mirror.h"
Mirror m1;
```

#### two.cpp

```
#include "mirror.h"
extern Mirror m1;
Mirror m2 (&m1);
```

#### three.cpp

```
#include "mirror.h"
extern Mirror m2;
Mirror m3 (&m2);
```

and so on. Finally,

#### five.cpp

```
#include "mirror.h"

#include <iostream>

extern Mirror m4;
Mirror m5 (&m4);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << m5.test() << std::endl;
}
```

m5.test() returns true. The task says, that I should change linking order, that m5.test() returns false. I have tried to use:

> init_priority (priority)
>
> In Standard C++, objects defined at namespace scope are guaranteed to be initialized in an order in strict accordance with that of their
> definitions in a given translation unit. No guarantee is made for
> initializations across translation units. However, GNU C++ allows
> users to control the order of initialization of objects defined at
> namespace scope with the init_priority attribute by specifying a
> relative priority, a constant integral expression currently bounded
> between 101 and 65535 inclusive. Lower numbers indicate a higher
> priority.

but no luck.

Full exercise text:

> In a header file, create a class Mirror that contains two data
> members: a pointer to a Mirror object and a bool. Give it two
> constructors: the default constructor initializes the bool to true and
> the Mirror pointer to zero. The second constructor takes as an
> argument a pointer to a Mirror object, which it assigns to the
> object’s internal pointer; it sets the bool to false. Add a member
> function test( ): if the object’s pointer is nonzero, it returns the
> value of test( ) called through the pointer. If the pointer is zero,
> it returns the bool. Now create five cpp files, each of which includes
> the Mirror header. The first cpp file defines a global Mirror object
> using the default constructor. The second file declares the object in
> the first file as extern, and defines a global Mirror object using the
> second constructor, with a pointer to the first object. Keep doing
> this until you reach the last file, which will also contain a global
> object definition. In that file, main( ) should call the test( )
> function and report the result. If the result is true, find out how to
> change the linking order for your linker and change it until the
> result is false.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this is. It's a lot easier to just write your code so it doesn't do initialization order stuff like this in the first place.

Comment: @Antimony: hum... it is the goal of the exercise to expose the issue, so I would say the OP is aware of it.

Comment: @Mat I know, it just doesn't seem like a useful exercise to me. I've never had to do it in any of the C++ projects I've worked on.

Comment: @Antimony: Sometimes people need to experience an issue first hand to admit it does exist :)

Comment: What exactly does "I tried to use init_priority" mean?  Could you show us how?

Comment: Yes, here is the code:
`
#include "mirror.h"

Mirror m1  __attribute__ ((init_priority (102)));
`
and so on in next source file (with increasing priority number). I have tried an opposite order of priority (causing and opposite linking order). I can not understand how linking order can affect on this particular example. Order of static initialization in not determined between different translation units, but it must be done before main(). So, if no any code in static initialization depends on each other (in this example, we need only address of variables), how m5.test() could return false?

Comment: I'm puzzled with this one too. I managed to spit out a simple python script to check all 5! permutations of objects passed to linker. No luck, always true on the output. Working on GCC 4.7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to change the order of the object files when passing them to the linker. This works reasonable for the toplevel code although different compilers use different approaches, i.e., it isn't portable. Also, for libraries you generally can't control the order in which the objects are included. For example, if you have

```
// file1.cpp
int main() {
}

// file2.cpp
#include <iostream>
static bool value = std::cout << "file2.cpp\n";

// file3.cpp
#include <iostream>
static bool value = std::cout << "file3.cpp\n";
```

... and you link two programs like this:

```
g++ -o tst1 file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
g++ -o tst2 file1.cpp file3.cpp file2.cpp
```

you will get different output for `tst1` and `tst2`, e.g.:

```
$ ./tst1
file2.cpp
file3.cpp
$ ./tst2
file3.cpp
file2.cpp
```

The overall moral is: don't do it. That is: don't use global objects. If you feel you absolutely need to use global objects, encapsulate them into functions, e.g.:

```
Type& global_value() {
    static Type value; // possibly with constructor arguments
    return value;
}
```

This way, `value` is initialized the first time it is accessed and there is no way to access it while it isn't constructed, yet. If you encapsulate all objects like this, you can guarantee that they are constructed in an appropriate order (unless you have a cyclic dependency in which case it can't be made to work and you should seriously rethink your design). The above approach encapsulating objects into function is, unfortunately, not thread-safe in C++ 2003. It is thread-safe in C++ 2011, however. Still, use of global variable is generally problematic and you definitely want to minimize their use.

Comment: To the top with you! I can't emphasize how important this is in C++. I won't disclose the number of times I raged until I figured why my pointers were invalid, because this is such a common problem..

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this exercise too.

I managed to write a small Python script to prepare makefile entries that link and test final executable using all possible permutation of object files:

```
import itertools

for perm in itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
    print '\tg++ u0{0}.o u0{1}.o u0{2}.o u0{3}.o u0{4}.o -o $@ && ./main.exe'.format(*perm)
```

After executing my make process it turned out, that all of the possible configurations yielded `true` value.

This is due to the fact, that all global (i.e. static) variables are guaranteed to be initialized before entering `main` function.

I defined a global `bool` variable that holds result from a `test()` function before `main`, something like this:

```
#include "mirror.h"

#include <iostream>

extern Mirror m4;
Mirror m5 (&m4);

bool result = m5.test();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Bingo! Some of the objects' permutations yielded `false` at the progam's output.

All static variables are initialized with zeroes before any of their possible constructors are called. In this exercise, the order in which constructors are called is the clue.

If any object in the depencence chain has not been initialized by constructor when a value of `result` variable is established, the result is `false` value (`self_` value is 0 and `logic_` value is false, so test function returns `false`).

When a `result` variable is evaluated before entering `main` function, there is such possibility and order of object files in a linker command has something to do with the result.